# Dataflow/ApacheBeam Limit input to the first X amount?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a bounded PCollection but i only want to get the first X amount of inputs and discard the rest. Is there a way to do this using Dataflow 2.X/ApacheBeam?

Comment: There isn't a way to do this natively in Apache Beam. You may be able to manipulate or query the input source in a specific way to only select the first X number of elements. What input source are you reading from?

Comment: Originally the input is the result of a query from a BigQuery Table. Then it goes through a few steps of processing and further filtration  before getting to the step where I need only the first million. However, I can’t put a limit on the query.

Comment: Maybe you could use the [Top](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Top.html) transform?

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @Andrew in his comments, maybe you can use the `Top` transform in Apache Beam (for [Java](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Top.html) or for [Python](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.4.0/apache_beam.transforms.combiners.html?highlight=top#apache_beam.transforms.combiners.Top.Of)). Specifically, the `Top.of()` function returns a *PTransform* with a *PCollection*, ordered by a comparator transform.

[Here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Top.html#of-int-ComparatorT-) you can find a simple example of use:

```
PCollection<Student> students = ...;
PCollection<List<Student>> top10Students = students.apply(Top.of(10, new CompareStudentsByAvgGrade()));
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370679/4482491) another example using the Apache Beam Python SDK, which works around the fact that a single element is returned in the *PCollection*.

Answer (score 1):

For a random sample of X elements, you can use the built-in Sample transform (for [Python](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/apache_beam.transforms.combiners.html#apache_beam.transforms.combiners.Sample) or [Java](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Sample.html)).

Here is an example that shows how to sample 10 elements from an example input of 100 elements:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms.combiners import Sample

with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner') as p:
    input = p | beam.Create(range(100))
    output = input | Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(10)
    output | beam.io.WriteToText('output')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the order and just want a sample of N items, then I think you should be able to use `beam.combiners.Sample.FixedSizeGlobally` as described here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/sample/